# The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to implement `emgu cv` in my windows application. I have downloaded [emgu cv version 2.2.1.1150](http://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/emgucv/emgucv/2.2.1/libemgucv-windows-x86-2.2.1.1150.exe), added all necessary references in project. I have also copied all the opencv dlls in project output folder. As I run project I get exception `OpenCV: The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)`

At this line
`haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");`

I searched a lot almost all the examples I have found is using the same code even official emgu cv tutorial on [face detection](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection) uses the same way to initialize `HaarCascade`.

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem too, the problem was that I had two versions of Emgucv installed, **Version 3.3.0.2826** and **Version 2.1.0.793.** I was using **Version 2.1.0.793** for the face detection but i accidentally copied the **haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml** of **Version 3.3.0.2826** and I got the same error message. So I Tried coping the **haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml** xml file from the **2.1.0.793** and it worked.

So I guess when you use the xml file from different versions of Emgucv in your Debug folder it throws this exception.
just copy the haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml from the current version of emgucv that you're currently using in your project.

Hope this helps.